# "Scrolling"-only Binding update of ItemsSource of ItemsControl. How to make refresh automatic?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, itemssource

In my **ViewModel**, I set items:

```
ViewModelApplication.CurrentRulesListViewModel.Items = mPOSRules;
ViewModelApplication.CurrentRulesListViewModel.OnPropertyChanged("Items");
```

For some reason, the list stays the same until I scroll at least 5 times away from the place where a new item should appear.

**Control**:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:RulesListItemControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel IsVirtualizing="True"
                                            VirtualizationMode="Recycling"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
           >
                        <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    Focusable="False">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: The PropertyChanged event for the Items property is ignored when you have not assigned a new collection instance. Consider using ObservableCollection as type of the Items property. Any added or removed items would automatically update the UI.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, I changed `List` to `ObservableCollection`, and that helped. Could you post this as an answer?